# Contour Integration: What is the function?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

[image]

I know that the integral around a closed path = 0 since there are no poles.

[image]

Why is the integral along the slanted path $\int_0^R e^{-x^2w^2} w dx$? If $w$ is defined to be along the slope, shouldn't it simply be $\int_0^R e^{-w^2} dw$?

Comment: See [Fresnel Integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral).

Answer (score 0):

If $w$ is the intersection between of the slant ray and the unit circle, then the segment can be parametrized with **negative** direction as $z=xw$ with $0 \leq x \leq R$.

Then $z^2=x^2w^2$ and $dz=w dx$.

$$\int_{slant}e^{-z^2} dz = -\int_{0}^R e^{-x^2w^2} wdx$$

Comment: the problem is I don't understand why $z=wx$?

Comment: @user44840 How do you parametrize the ray $[0,w)$?

Comment: What is $[0,w)$?

Comment: @user44840 The half line starting at $0$ and passing through $w$...If you don't know, how do you parametrize the line through two points? Use the formula for $0$ and $w$ as the two points.

Comment: $w = Re^{i arg w}$

Comment: @user44840 If $w$ is on the unit circle what is $e^{i arg w}$? And you should not use $R$ as it is already used to denote the radius of the sector.. Use a different letter, lets say... $x$ ;)

Comment: @user44840 Note that the line between the points $z_1, z_2$ can also be parametrized by $z=z_1+t(z_2-z_1)$. Which, in this case, leads to the parametrization $z=0+tw$.

Comment: If w is on a unit circle, $e^{i arg w} = cos (arg w) + i sin(arg w)$.

Sorry this is one of the moments whereby I have a gut feeling it is really simple, and I'm completely missing the point!

Comment: @user44840 If $w$ is on the unit circle, then $w= cos (arg w) + i sin(arg w)=e^{i arg w}$ ;)

Comment: @ N.S. Still it doesn't show that $z=wx$..

Comment: @user44840 In general I suppose i'd advise going back over the geometric intuition of complex arithmetic. You seem to have a very formulaic approach to it all that is clouding some things. Now, letting $t$ (which we could also call $x$) run from 0 to 1, what does the curve $t \mapsto tw$ look like?